# how to disable website work with public link

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, public

how can I disable public ? my website works with both `public` and `without public`

my website product page working fine
https://exmple.com/product-slug

I have explored its work with `public` in link
https://exmple.com/public/product-slug

using larave 8 with https

my `htacsses` file content:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     #Session timeout
    
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    
    RewriteEngine On
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php
    
    </IfModule>
    
    # BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
    # Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
    # To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
    # For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
    <IfModule php7_module>
       php_flag display_errors Off
       php_value max_execution_time 30
       php_value max_input_time 60
       php_value max_input_vars 1000
       php_value memory_limit 2048M
       php_value post_max_size 8M
       php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
       php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73"
       php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
       php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule lsapi_module>
       php_flag display_errors Off
       php_value max_execution_time 30
       php_value max_input_time 60
       php_value max_input_vars 1000
       php_value memory_limit 2048M
       php_value post_max_size 8M
       php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
       php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73"
       php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
       php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
    </IfModule>
    # END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
    
    # php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
    # Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
    <IfModule mime_module>
      AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
    </IfModule>
    # php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: You should be editing your `DocumentRoot` to point to the public folder. The way you have it set up currently is **dangerous**.

Comment: @ceejayoz can you explain more? what i need to fix in my .htaccess

Comment: @AhmedSaad what you need to fix is not your .htaccess file but your hosting setup.